# foreign key mismatch - "app_employee" referencing "app_mycustomeuser"

Tags: python, django

I am working with a custom build user model in **Django**. My app name is `app`.

my **models.py**:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='employee_releted_user')
    industry = models.OneToOneField(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_releted_industry')
    i_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    employee_varified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Inspector(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='inspector_releted_user')
    inspector_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='admin_releted_user')
    admin_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

There was also a `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.myCustomeUser'` in my **settings.py**.

I have drop my full database, then I run `makemigrations` and it reported totally normal as `No changes detected in app 'app'`.
But after that when I run `migrate` command it shows following error in my terminal:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: app
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying app.0001_initial... OK
  Applying app.0002_auto_20210104_1849...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 394, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "app_employee" referencing "app_mycustomeuser"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line   
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 247, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 307, in check_constraints
    violations = self.cursor().execute('PRAGMA foreign_key_check').fetchall()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 394, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "app_employee" referencing "app_mycustomeuser"
PS D:\Project\django\hackathon practice\ProjectSurokkhaBeta_1.2>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you delete delete your migration files from migration folders as well after dropping db ?

Comment: No, but after you suggest I just remove all the files from `migration` folder inside the 'app' folder. Now `migrate` and `makemigrations` are working smoothly! but another problem is occers. I cannot create `superuser`, It says `no such table: app_mycustomeuser`

Comment: Check your db, it should have a table named "app_mycustomeuser", if not, your changes weren't migrated to the database. Are you sure, you did run python manage.py migrate command after running makemigrations ?

Comment: yes, I was run that but it didn't work. However now I can find the bug, I also delete the `__init__.py` of that folder which was needed for `createsuperuser`, Now I place there another `__init__.py` from the fully new project's app and now all of that works perfectly!

Comment: Of course, an __init__.py file should be there.